# Turn off input validation for a single field

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I've got an ASP.NET 4 site on which I want to allow people to put '<' in their password. However, .NET gets in the way by blocking (what it sees as) an attempt to put HTML in a form field. I know I can turn off input validation entirely, but I only want to turn it off for this one field. Does anyone know an easy way to do that?

Comment: Is there any special reason that you need < to be in a password?

Comment: @eddy556 - does he need a special reason?

Comment: @Oded - Sure he does, I can understand the advantages of having an extra character, but if thats true why does he only want to allow < and not other script characters? > comes to mind.

Comment: @eddy556 I actually do want to allow any character; < was just the one that was throwing errors at me, so it was at the top of my mind.

Comment: @eddy556 - I have been to too many sites that have arbitrary rules on what passwords are allowed. Even if I _want_ a secure password, I can't have it... So, asking about enabling better password entry is a no-brainer for me and requires no reson.

Comment: @Oded - Well said.  I didn't have any issue with allowing the extra characters (as long as it is *only* the single field).  I was just wanting to know the reasoning behind the question incase turning off input validation wasn't the best way forward...

Comment: The .NET framework should automatically allow all characters in password fields IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only turn off input validation for the entire page.  The only solution I can think of is to turn off the input validation, and then scrub all the other (non-password) input fields using something like [Anti-XSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a link without quoting the example. Dead link now

Comment: It's not an example, it was a link to a library that provides anti-xss functionality.  Now at https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/4.3.0.

Comment: Ok sorry, but now I can't undo my down-vote. Could you edit your post with the new link so I can do so?

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with .NET 4.5.

Update your Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
```

Then set `ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"` on your password controls:

```
<asp:YourControl id="YourControl" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"/>
```

Note - after updating web.config, you might run into the error `WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'.` See [ASP.Net 2012 Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery) for more info on that.

More info on RequestValidationMode 4.5: [requestValidationMode 4.5 vs 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590032/requestvalidationmode-4-5-vs-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn input validation off for the single MVC action using the [ValidateInputAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx). Since you're only accepting username/password (I would assume) you should be able to scrub input yourself of any invalid characters. Use the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) to do that.

Comment: This is Webforms, not MVC, and I have a lot of inputs on this page. Otherwise that would work great :)

Comment: Mah bad. There is a ValidateRequest property on the @Page directive that you can use to turn off validation only for that particular page, but I think that's as granular as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Note in ASP.NET 4 and higher to get ValidateRequest in the @Page directive to work you need to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to web.config. See this page for details:
[http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)

But this is my preferred approach:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public class HtmlTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection)
        {
            bool res = base.LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection);
            Text = Text.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&amp;", "&");
            return res;
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);

            ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), "htmlTextBox" + UniqueID, "try { var item = document.getElementsByName('" + UniqueID + "')[0]; item.value = item.value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); } catch (err) {}");
        }
    }
}
```

And then register the control in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="uc1" namespace="Controls" />
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

This way you can just use `<uc1:HtmlTextBox runat="server" />` if you want to allow the textbox to post html, but other controls on the page will still be blocked from posting html unlike the approach of turning ValidateRequest off.

Comment: This is a clever answer, but would not work for the password field in the OP where the content would need to be preserved. Please suggest how to do this for a password field (HTML Decode, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Just add `[AllowHtml]` on the property that should not be validated.

see [ValidateInputAttribute does not contain a definition for Exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754732/validateinputattribute-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-exclude)

Comment: This answer applies to MVC, but the question was about WebForms.