# ValidateInputAttribute does not contain a definition for Exclude

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 3, and I'm trying to exclude some fields from validation in a create action.

I see several examples showing how to exclude fields using [ValidateInput(true, Exclude = "xxxx")], but when I try this, I get this error:

"ValidateInputAttribute does not contain a definition for Exclude"

Any thougts?

Edit:

I have a partial class that looks like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Article_Validation))]
public partial class article
{

}

public class Article_Validation
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int article_id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string article_title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is required")]
    public string article_body { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public DateTime article_datecreared { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public DateTime article_datemodified { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int article_viewcount { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Abstract is required")]
    public string article_abstract { get; set; }

}
```

The [AllowHtml] is placed on two properties, but I still get the error. I was under the impressionthat this class would be "merged" with the EF class of the same name?

If I put [ValidateInput(false)] on the controller, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting [ValidateInput(false)] on the action methods for create and update, in order for the html to pass through. Maybe not the preferred solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the examples you are seeing are wrong. There is no such property on ValidateInputAttribute that I can see. If you are trying to allow html you can do this on your model to get to the specific property:

```
public class Foo
{
    [AllowHtml]        
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

But I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to set up a rich text editor, so I need to, as you say, allow html. Ok, so I have a partial class in my model that is merged with the entity framework class. I use this class for validation etc. Can I just put the [AllowHtml] on the specific field there?

Comment: @Soeren - Not sure if it works the way you are showing in your edit. I use it effectively with EF Code First and I am sure it would work the same with POCO, but I have never tried it with a buddy class.

Answer (score 0):

"Exclude" parameter doesn't exists in MVC 3. You could find it only in some developer versions such as MVC 3 RC.