# VB 2012, Empty Web Project, Login Form...But error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Following [Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I get an error:

KeyPoint

1. After Make Empty Web Project
2. Then Make Default.aspx
3. Then Make Login.aspx
4. Then Add login form on Login.aspx

But Error

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following in the `Application_Start` event of Global.asax:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
    new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
  Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
  DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
  CdnPath = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
  CdnDebugPath = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
});
```

Replacing the `Path` and `DebugPath` with your actual `.js` paths. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery) answer as well.