# ASP.Net 2012 Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery: What now?

Tags: asp.net

the first thing that you would like to answer is : refer to this post:
[ASP.Net 2012 Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery)

Now, I have the same problem and I have used the fix which works for me:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Noting that I know very little about ASP and .NET, how safe/advised is it to disable Unobtrusive Validation ?

Will it break anything? Is it a weak fix for the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in:
What's New in ASP.NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012

I am copying the relevant text below:

> **[Unobtrusive Validation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc318097392)**
>
> You can now configure the built-in validator controls to use
>   unobtrusive JavaScript for client-side validation logic. This
>   significantly reduces the amount of JavaScript rendered inline in the
>   page markup and reduces the overall page size. You can configure
>   unobtrusive JavaScript for validator controls in any of these ways:
>
> - Globally by adding the following setting to the `<appSettings>` element in the Web.config file:
> - Globally by setting the static `System.Web.UI.ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode` property
>     to `UnobtrusiveValidationMode.WebForms` (typically in the
>     `Application_Start` method in the Global.asax file).
> - Individually for a page by setting the new UnobtrusiveValidationMode property of the Page class to
>     `UnobtrusiveValidationMode.WebForms`.

In this blog: [Jupaol's coding adventures](http://jupaol.blogspot.mx/2012/09/enabling-unobtrusive-validation-from.html). I found:

In order to fix the previous exception, we need to install the following Nuget packages:

- jQuery
- ASPNET.ScriptManager.jQuery
- Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.MSAjax
- Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms

Also there is a detail of the code added by these Nuget packages.