# Can't have more then one RequiredFieldValidator in ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

Okay so whenever i have more then one  `RequiredFieldValidator` in my ASP.NET web forms i get the following error:

`WebForms` `UnobtrusiveValidationMode` requires a `ScriptResourceMapping` for 'jquery'. Please add a `ScriptResourceMapping` named jquery(case-sensitive).

I must be missing something really obvious here

Thanks

Comment: Did you search before posting? Welcome to SO :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery

Comment: I cant see to add the appSetting tag?