# RegularExpressionValidator on Text Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

Is this possible?

I have Two textboxes using RegularExpressionValidator, it's checking for "," and if there is no comma i'd like it to clear the Textbox and show error message next to the textbox.

And if this is not possible, what could i use to check for "," in the value that's being input?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to check for the presence of a comma and then clear a textbox if validation fails.

1. To check for the presence of a comma, make the ValidationExpression: 
   ".*,.*"   i.e:

   `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="valRgx" ControlToValidate="txtBox" ValidationExpression=".*,.*" ErrorMessage="Must contain a comma" />`
2. To check whether or not you need to clear the text box, assuming a full postback, override the page prerender event and if your validation has failed clear the textbox:

i.e.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!NameOfValidator.IsValid) TextBoxName.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To answer your question about accepting F4 on its own or your barcode pattern:

`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="valRgx" ControlToValidate="txtBox" ValidationExpression="(F4)|(.*,.*)" ErrorMessage="Must contain a comma" />`

Comment: Is it possible to exclude something like "FF" from that expression? If someone types that, allow it to go through other then that spit out the error?

Comment: If you tell me exactly what you are trying to match with an example I can try to help you

Comment: Okay, i have a textbox that'll be used to scan barcodes. And barcode contains values like [these](http://i.imgur.com/AM3CRmK.png). But sometimes there is "F4" as value. What that does it clears out certain fields and starts the process over again. When it scans "f4" it doesn't get inserted into database. Hope this helps.

Comment: So to clarify, do you want to accept F4 as valid or refuse it? It sounds like F4 is a valid command so you should let it through the validation - but then do the appropriate logic

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ErrorMessage="Comma is required" ControlToValidate="tb1" runat="server" ValidationExpression=".*,.*" ForeColor="Red"/>
```

EDIT: Include the javascript function for clear textbox when validation fails.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" OnChange="tbOnChange();" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="tbVal" ErrorMessage="Comma is required" ControlToValidate="tb1" runat="server" ValidationExpression=".*,.*" ForeColor="Red" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tbOnChange() {
            if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") return;
            if (!tbVal.isvalid) {
                var tb1 = document.getElementById('tb1');
                tb1.value = '';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Regards

k

Comment: When i tried this i get the following:
`Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).` 
Need to try with javascript.

Comment: Hi, check this question [Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery)

Comment: Yeh i was able to find that and added it. But the other answer approach was i was looking for. Thanks though. Saved for later ref.