# E-mail validation is ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

When I try to validate the input in my textBox and it gives me this error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +2179162
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +10
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9708897
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Im using this to check my validation:

```
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailError" 
         runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" 
         ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
         ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid E-mail"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And when my login button is pressed I call this method:

```
if (emailError.IsValid == true)
        {
            String user = email.Text;
            String pass = password.Text;
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\MaxNie\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\TextFiles\\TextFile1.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                String[] line = lines[i].Split(',');
                if (user.Equals(line[0]) && pass.Equals(line[1]))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Locations.aspx");
                }
                else { errorLabel.Visible = true; }
            }
        }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net 2012 Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery)

Comment: Looks like the error message you're getting is telling you exactly how to fix it. `Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).`

Comment: Im aware, but I started with C# and ASP.NET 2 days ago so ull have to excuse me if I dont know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you could disable the Unobstrusive validation mode is with the line:

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    ...

 <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

So modify your config file.
If that doesn't work, follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

Answer (score 0):

I would look at disabling the "Unobtrusive Validation Mode" in either the Web.Config or Global.asax.

Protip:

You can just use `if (emailError.IsValid)` instead of `if(emailError.IsValid == true)`

Answer (score -1):

I know this might not be the direction you want to take this but my suggestion would be to use a jQuery based validator. These .Net validatiors are more trouble than they are worth IMHO

Something like

```
$("#email").on("blur", validateEmail);
function() {
    if(/yourRegEx/.test(this.value)) {
       $(this).next().show();
       this.IsValid = false;
    } else {
       $(this).next().hide();
       this.IsValid = true;
    }
}
function formOnSubmit() { //<-- you need to wire this up
    for(var i in this.getElementsByTagName("input")) {
       if(! i.IsValid) e.preventDefault
    }
}
<input id=email /><div style="display:none">Invalid email</div>
```

Comment: You can't just do that.  Your client could easily (deliberately or not) bypass it and now you have nothing stopping him.

Comment: Obviously this addresses the client side. Yes I agree that /yourRegEx/ should also be on the server