# ASP.NET output error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I am running my aspx page it is building successfully but am getting following error in browser.

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +2169078
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +10
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +9579521
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

What is this error and how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery

follow this link . Might be able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Add this into your `web.config` file:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

**Solution 2:**

Register `jQuery` in `Global.asax` in the `Application_Start` event like this:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
    new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
});
```