# InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation, server-error

I've a web form with a text box and RequiredFieldValidator Control.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
   Name : <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">       
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:button runat="server" text="Button" />
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page and click on the button, I get an error saying

Error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).]
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureJqueryRegistered() +145
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.RegisterUnobtrusiveScript() +11
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +88
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +166
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4682
```

I did some googling and found some solutions like changing the target version to 4.0 in web.config, using jquery in the global.asax file and changing the property of UnobtrusiveValidationMode to none.

I even read about unobtrusive javascript at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript. But I could not make any relation with the content given there and the error I encountered

Most of the answers said to refer http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735928/in-asp-net-web-application-visual-basic-the-requiredfieldvalidator-doest-work

But this link no longer exists.

When I viewed the source of the web page after changing the target version to 4.0, I found some extra inline javascripts(I guess that's called obtrusive javascripts). What's wrong in using inline codes?

I'm pretty new to ASP.net, so little brevity appreciated.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery

Comment: As I said, that post also gives the solutions, I want to know why and how this error was encountered.

Comment: Just add **script manager** tag before form element and the exception will be disappear

Comment: Why it disappears?

Comment: @Prathapa reddy,After the raise of HTML5 ,asp.net which used default validation as webforms changed to html5.So ,you need to override the default validation (HTML5) to webforms(server side/None) that is what Unobtrusive javascript mean.