# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have this error in an asp.net page when running my page. I have a ckeditor on the page and when writing in then editor and saving my changes, this error occurs. And I have this code in the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"
```

and I have this code in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </httpModules>
      </system.web>
```

and this is error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Textbody="<p>hello</p>
").
```

How do I solve problem؟؟

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Try looking here, I see that you have already set "validateRequest" to false, but you may be missing a setting http://codingstill.com/2013/01/avoiding-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected/

Comment: the link not useful.I use visual studio 2013 and .net is 4.5 and in each page ValidateRequest is false but this error occurs.please help

Comment: I think you need to check that link again, specifically pertaining requestValidationMode. or look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590032/requestvalidationmode-4-5-vs-2-0